# Spring: Registration form remove object from model

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC Project I created a registration page.In this page there is a form in which the user insert his information(name,surname and so on).I have used the Spring tag form to bind the object "cliente" to the form. In my controller I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/registration",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewRegistration(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("cliente",clienteFactory.createCliente());
    return "registrazione";
}//registrazione
```

In registration.jsp

```
<form:form method="post" action="add" modelAttribute="cliente">
     ....
</form:form>
```

In this project I have not used Spring Security,because I'm a student and I hadn't learned  this part yet. 
If the user leaves the page without register, I want to delete the object "Cliente" from the model.How can I solve it?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you don't need to delete object from model as if client leaves page with mapping /registration model ref will be overriden with model of another mapping method.

Second in more cases it's no good idea to call your method clienteFactory.createCliente()) in GET request method. Better to call it in POST after user fill all form fields and post his request than you know that you need to call clientFactory.Also use [@ModelAttribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) annotation as method argument.

As you have in your form `form:form method="post"` it will not working without such method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/registration",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String makeRegistration(ModelMap model){
.....
```

Also see simple [Sring tutorial for handling forms](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/).

Comment: If i change to "post" i have: HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: sure! Best practice to have 2 methods mapping one for get and one for post. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Comment: Because in jsp I call `<a href="registration">Registration</a>`